# Import a npm package (with fonts) from a SASS file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, fonts

I would like to import `simple-line-icons` directly as a module and change the prefix `$simple-line-icon-prefix` to something else.

I've created a test project:

```
vue create foobar
cd foobar
npm install -D sass-loader sass
npm install -D simple-line-icons
```

Then added the import directive into `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'    
import 'simple-line-icons/scss/simple-line-icons.scss'

Vue.config.productionTip = false    
new Vue({ render: h => h(App) }).$mount('#app')
```

Then my component is just this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">Hello <i class="icon-people"></i> world</div>
</template>
```

This work great but I would like to change a variable into the `scss` file so I created a `main.scss`

```
$simple-line-icon-prefix: "foobar-";    
@import 'simple-line-icons/scss/simple-line-icons.scss'
```

Then replace the import accordingly in `main.js`: `import './main.scss'`.

Now I have an issue with the fonts:

```
These relative modules were not found:

* ../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot?v=2.4.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??
ref--8-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/
sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-3-3!./src/main.scss
```

How can I import a npm package from scss?

**EDIT**

I was able to change the font path with:

```
$simple-line-font-path: "~simple-line-icons/fonts/";
@import '~simple-line-icons/scss/simple-line-icons.scss'
```

Then I don't have any errors, but the font is not loaded into the browser :(

Comment: is main.scss in src directory?

Comment: Yes it is next to App.vue and main.js